# Mathjax at Sound Design?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

Why doesn't this site have MathJax activated?  I've seen several questions and a few answers that are trying to use it, but it obviously isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because sites do not have MathJax enabled unless the demand is great enough (as it adds load.) We are nowhere near the usual threshold for SE to enable this.

Comment: To add a bit more detail, the problem with MathJax and the current way SE implements it, it is loaded on every single page load for a site, whether it is used or not.  This means that there is a human detectable delay in page load times for every page on sites where it is active.